# this.setState not working properly; child props inherit wrong information - React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am relatively new to React Native and I am trying to create a custom Calendar and I am running into some problems regarding this.setState. Basically when I have the code this.setState in the componentDidMount() function and it prints the right number; However, when I did console.log in my Calendar class, it says that my month is 0 (innitial value).

I have tried:

- having a function in the constructor (ie. this.updateCurrentCalendar()) and ran that in the constructor (returned unmounted error)
- ComponentDidMount() before render (current version)

Here is my CalendarPage code:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    var tMonth =  parseInt(new Date().getMonth()+1);
    var tYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());

    //ran ,()=>console.log after the first argument in this.setState and returns the correct month
    this.setState({trackMonth: tMonth, trackYear: tYear});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style = {styles.CalendarViewStyle}>
        <Calendar style = {styles.CalendarStyle} thisMonth = {this.state.trackMonth} thisYear = {this.trackYear}/>
        <Button
          title = "Next"
          onPress = {()=>this.setState({trackMonth: this.state.trackMonth+1})}/>
        <Button
          title = "Back"
          onPress = {()=>this.setState({trackMonth: this.state.trackMonth-1})}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

And Here is my Calendar code:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    //console.log(this.state.monthStartDay) says it is 0 here*
    //finding the maximum day in a month
    var maxDay = this.findMaxDate(this.state.monthDate);
    this.setState({maxDate: maxDay});

    //finding which day does the first day of the path starts
    var startDay = this.findDay(1);
    this.setState({monthStartDay: startDay});

    //first week start day (if first day of the month does not start on monday)
    var fLineStartDate = this.findFirstLineStartDate();
    this.setState({firstLineStartDate: fLineStartDate});

    //second week start day
    var sLineStartDate = this.findSecondStartLine(fLineStartDate+7);
    this.setState({secondLineStartDate: sLineStartDate});
  }

  render(){
    var lastMaxDay = this.findMaxDate(this.state.monthDate-1);
    return(
      <View style = {styles.CalendarViewStyle}>
        <CalendarLine
          style = {styles.CalendarLineStyle}
          item = {{lineDay: this.state.firstLineStartDate, maxDay: this.state.maxDate, lineNum: 0, lastMaxDay: lastMaxDay}}/>
      </View>
```

Thank you very much for the help!

EDIT:
This is my constructor in my Calendar class

```
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        monthStartDay: 0,
        firstLineStartDate: 0,
        secondLineStartDate: 0,
        monthDate: this.props.thisMonth,
        yearDate: this.props.thisYear,
        maxDate:0,
      };
    this.findDay = this.findDay.bind(this);
    this.findMaxDate = this.findMaxDate.bind(this);
    this.findLeapYear = this.findLeapYear.bind(this);
    this.findFirstLineStartDate = this.findFirstLineStartDate.bind(this);
    this.findSecondStartLine = this.findSecondStartLine.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: but the variable are different in both classes.

Comment: ahh right. I did _this.props.thisMonth_ in my _this.state_ (ie. this.state = {monthDate: this.props.thisMonth, ...})

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the props passed to the Calendar class without assigning them to your state constructor

var lastMaxDay = this.findMaxDate(this.state.monthDate-1);

rather use:

var lastMaxDay = this.findMaxDate(this.props.monthDate-1);

As you are receiving these as props, I am assuming you are not going to be calling setState on them from within the Calendar class?

By assigning them to state in the calendar class you are trying to setState in 2 different classes with one setState call.

Comment: ahh right, because the Calendar I am trying to create is able to switch between different months and year (so the first page will show the calendar for the current year and month; click on the next button will show the next month's calendar); and I am relatively new to React Native and I read somewhere that I dynamic data should be in states. So I try to put everything in states

Comment: I have just tried doing that but it is still not working... It is still telling me that the value is 0. I dont think it updated the state's trackMonth...

Answer (score 0):

```
this.tMonth =  parseInt(new Date().getMonth()+1);
this.tYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
```

keep this in constructor and pass the variable to Calendar component

Comment: This temporarily fixed the part in _CalendarPage_ where I had to pass the data to _Calendar_, but in the _Calendar_ it is still not passing the data to its child. I have just done some testing and turns out that componentDidMount works, but it only triggered after it pass in the wrong data (i.e. it loads the data with maxMonth=0, then only loads the data with maxMonth =31)